# Turning WiFi Access Point ON/OFF

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

I've just created a WiFi AP on my RPi 3. I'd like to use it with my DSLR, so I don't need network if I want to do some timelapse. Now that works great, but I would like to use mainly "the normal way" my WiFi. Can I wrote a script or so (sorry I
 am quite new to linux) to turn it ON or OFF?

Please let me know if you need further information.
Thanks!

Comment: you could use `wait [FOR CERTAIN SECONDS OR HOURS]` and `ifconfig wlan0 down` to switch off wifi after the wait period is over or use `crontab` to trigger the same command at every hour, minute of the day as per your wish..

Comment: I meant I want to have a "switch" to switch between AP and normal WiFi usage.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this works for your requirements, but what I do to turn my Access Point off is:

```
sudo systemctl stop hostapd
```

This turns the AP off and makes it available for normal WLAN usage. To turn it on again just start the `hostapd` daemon again.